# wordpress - jQuery is not defined - wp/admin

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm using e clean install of `wordpress` 5.3.2, and in the `wp-admin` i keep getting the error `jQuery` is not defined, i remove all plugins, check the `htacess` and some tutorials about how fixed, but nothing worked

[image: error img]

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding this in your wp-config.php

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
```

Thanks

Comment: @Alberto wlcm brother :)